# A problem for math lovers to count the digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, popular-math

Today a classmate of mine asked a question which is based on counting.

**Question.**
*Find a positive integer which when multiplied up to $6$ times will give numbers having the same digits but rearranged and after that will give a number with all nines.*

I have checked up to $100000$ but no such number is found.

Please help if you could suggest any ideas. Is there any general rule?

Comment: I found the statement of the question a little vague. If you can restate it in a more descriptive way.

Comment: yes i also agree you the second condition is not explicit but i firstly i was trying to find no. which setisfy first condition

Comment: I think the number you're looking for is $142857$. Maybe your check didn't find this one, as you say you went to 100000...

Comment: Ok i"ll check but if u can show the proof of second condition.

Comment: who downvote me plz give reason so i"ll take care at next time

Comment: @Blue It probably means that any number of additions less than 7 permutes the digits in the original number.

Comment: yes i find that Thank u all so much .but i didn't set statement it was the original given to me

Answer (score 14):

Multiples of $142857$:
\begin{align}
1\times 142857=142857\\
2\times 142857=285714\\ 
3\times 142857=428571\\ 
4\times 142857=571428\\
5\times 142857=714285\\ 
6\times 142857=857142\\ 
7\times 142857=999999
\end{align}

**Note.** If $N=0588235294117647$, then $2N,3N,\ldots,18N$ have the same digits as $N$ cyclically rearranged (that's why the 0 in front of $N$), and $18N=999999999999999999$, and this phenomenon is related with the fact that $19$ divides $10^{18}-1$, but it does not divide $10^{k}-1$, for $k<18$, as in the case of $142857$, where $7\mid 10^6-1$, but $7\not\mid 10^k-1$, for $k<6$.

Also, this phenomenon is present in every number system - See  [Cyclic rearrangements of periods of the decimal expansions of certain rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676396/cyclic-rearrangements-of-periods-of-certain-periodic-numbers).

Comment: Clearly, the author just needed to check a little further) +1

Answer (score 8):

There's no need to check values up to 100000 --- there's a simple way to find the answer. You want 7 times the number to be all nines. So you want to look at the numbers 9, 99, 999, and so on, until you find one that is a multiple of 7. And the first one that works is 999999, which is 7 times 142857. Then you just have to check that the other multiples of 142857 behave the way they are asked to behave.

EDIT: Bonus question --- what if you want the 16th addition (instead of the 6th) to give all nines?